# Disable page scroll but allow Google map scroll

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, appmobi, appframework

I have an app using appmobi/xdk/appframework when I put in the package

It disables the scrollinf of the page vertically on the iPhone. However, it also disables the scrolling of the Google map on the page. Any ideas on how to re-enable the map scrolling?

Comment: Can you post your code so I can help a little bit here

Comment: Do you know how to do what your doing but without google maps? Just a plain div.. say i have a list (ul, li) that i want to scroll and nothing else on the page. how would i go about that? I tried your answers but nothing seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Just add scrolling="no" in your panel and data-footer="none" if u want more space for map

```
<div id="main" class="panel" selected="true" scrolling="no" data-footer="none">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--If your are using the appmobi 3.4.0 platform -->
<div id="#pagetitle" title="Yourtitle" class="panel" scrolling="no">

<div id="map-google" style="overflow:visible;">


</div>

</div>

<!--If your are using the appmobi/intel XDK 4.0 platform-->

<div id="#pagetitle" title="Yourtitle" class="panel" style="overflow:hidden;">

<div id="map-google" style="overflow:visible;">

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the key is to add `style="overflow:hidden"` on your panel.

Here is sample code with appframework + google maps: http://jsbin.com/UKaQetO/1/edit

works on iphone,android and windows phone.

Comment: Do you know how to do what your doing but without google maps? Just a plain div.. say i have a list (ul, li) that i want to scroll and nothing else on the page. how would i go about that? I tried your answers but nothing seem to work.