# Disable page scrolling and allow Google Maps scrolling in Appframework 2.1 with enabled af.scrolling plugin

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, appframework

I tried this solutions: [Disable page scroll but allow Google map scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486222/disable-page-scroll-but-allow-goggle-map-scroll/23932051?noredirect=1#comment36862356_23932051)

but it only works if I completely leave the plugin library of appframework out of my application. If I add plugins I can prevent scrolling with

```
style="overflow:hidden"
```

but I can't move the map in mashup. Here is an example

http://jsbin.com/mediqelo/1/edit?html,output

Remove

```
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/01org/appframework/master/build/af.plugins.min.js"></script>
```

works but is not option for me. Is there a trick to use google maps in actual appframework while using the plugin library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating an issue and a short discussion with a developer I got the problem.
(https://github.com/01org/appframework/issues/699)

1) The appframework.ui.min.js includes a lot of plugins but not the af.desktopBrowsers plugin. Scrolling won't work in desktop Browsers without adding this plugin. This plugin freezes the Google Map mashup. It seems that the developer don't see a problem with this because Chrome is not a target platfrom (I am also not worried about it).

2) In Windows Phone 8 the af.desktopBrowsers is needed (strange) because of mapping mspointer events to touch events. But on this platform Google Map works with af.desktopBrowsers (yippie!).

The appframework kitchen sink app has a small snippet to load the af.deskopBrowser if needed:

```
if (!((window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch) || 'ontouchstart' in window)) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "plugins/af.desktopBrowsers.js";
    var tag = $("head").append(script);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`appframework.ui.min.js` script file already has most of the plugins included (af.scroller and more), so you dont need af.plugins.js.

Here is list of plugins included in `appframework.ui.min.js`: https://github.com/01org/appframework/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L132

So the error you are seeing may be caused by including plugins 2 times.

If you want other missing plugins, you can include individual plugins from this location: https://github.com/01org/appframework/tree/master/plugins, (af.slidemenu and af.desktopBrowsers are the ones missing in the `appframework.ui.min.js`)

Comment: If I remove the plugins JS file I can't use the scroller anymore. I extended my example by a second view with a list (http://jsbin.com/mediqelo/3/edit?html,output)